# How to split a column in a datatable/datagridview into four columns with regex in VB.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, datagridview, datatable, split

I need to split up the string content of the fifth column in the datagridview into the next four columns for each row. For this I am using regular expressions to extract the specific parts of the string.

I wrote a for loop to go through the column of the datagridview that I am trying to split and tried to save the cell values into an array, so that I can use them to loop through each item with regex. Then I wanted to save the matches in a listbox.

```
Dim columnValues() As String
Dim RegMatches As ListBox = Nothing
Dim my1Regex As Regex = New Regex("[a|A]Bla")

For i As Integer = 0 To ErrorsDgV.Rows.Count - 1
    ReDim Preserve columnValues(i)
    columnValues(i) = ErrorsDgV.Item(5, i).Value

    For Each j As String In columnValues(i)
        If my1Regex.IsMatch(j) Then
            RegMatches.Items.Add(j)
        End If
    Next
    ErrorsDgV.Item(6, i).Value = RegMatches
Next
```

I get a System.NullReferenceException. It says that the temporary local variable of the type String is "Nothing".

Edit:
This is what I am  loading into ErrorsDgV.Item(5, i).Value:

```
Dim myregex As Regex = New Regex("S[0-6]")
Dim MTable As DataTable
    MTable = datasetB.Tables("BLABLA").Select().
    Where(Function(r) myregex.IsMatch(r.Item("Data"))).ToArray().CopyToDataTable

ErrorsDgV.DataSource = MTable
```

The fifth column of the datagridview contains a string.

Comment: Could you please show us what you are loading into ErrorsDgV.Item(5, i).Value?

Comment: `Dim RegMatches As ListBox = Nothing` - why? Also, `[a|A]` matches `A`, `a` and `|`, did you intend to write `[aA]`?

Comment: Hi! I edited my post and yes thank you I intended to write [aA]